# Getting error on opening sqlite db in assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm getting `NullpointerException` while trying to access `db` in `Assets` folder. And the `db` is indicated red in color on `Assets` folder.

[Image containing Db in Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT4P3.jpg)

```
public void createdatabase() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(" came into Create database ");
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    System.out.println(" myinput = "+myinput.toString());
    System.out.println(" Got input ");

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    System.out.println(" outfilename = "+outfilename);

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    System.out.println(" created outputStream");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}
```

Is there any way to check the db values in String?

Comment: post your code for getting db from asset

Comment: but the code is stop executing at myinput showing nullPointerException

Comment: the you getting is not right way to get db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384

Comment: private static String getDatabasePath(Context _context, String _databaseName) {
    return "/data/data/"+_context.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+_databaseName;
}

Comment: The thing is i need to get data from Assets --> db and should store that in /data/data/.... path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `The thing is i need to get data from Assets -` You want to copy a file from assets to internal memory. Thats what you want. You should have used that as subject too. That it is a sqlite file is irrelevant for the problem. A file is a file.

Comment: if i follow the same process in new project it is functioning properly, but if i implement it in my existing project it is passing error in this line 'InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);'

Comment: Passing error? Please show the complete exception message. Copy from logcat. Then `mycontext` will be null. Or mycontext.getAssets().

Answer (score 0):

DB_NAME does not match with the name of the file in assets folder.

Any reason why you did not tell the values?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? That would throw a `FileNotFoundException`, not a `NullPointerException`. I mean, I'm not saying you're wrong. They very well may have the wrong name, but the immediate issue is a NPE, apparently. Did I miss some comments?

Comment: Well tell the value of DB_NAME. And the file name. Compare. They are not equal. Why didnt you post both values if i suggest that they are not equal? And i even asked you to tell the values. Unbelievable.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I was just asking if they'd mentioned the value of `DB_NAME` in some comment I'd missed that had been deleted.

Comment: Sorry, i oversaw. This is such a confusing post. Indeed a null pointer exception first. Sorry.  A null context i think.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm betting, too.

Comment: I got the output, there is nothing wrong with the code. Anyway thanks all